# why is 'nocorrect' being ignored by ZSH?

Tags: shell, zsh, autocorrect

I have a script that invokes a new shell and runs a generated command. This is what a typical command looks like:

`exec nocorrect vim file:///rails_app/app/controllers/cow_controller.rb +214`

I thought adding the 'nocorrect' would solve my problem, but when the above line is run I still get *'zsh: correct 'vim' to '.vim' [nyae]?'*. What am I missing ?

(For background, I'm using [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) which generates urls with line numbers, and [vim _in_iterm](https://github.com/phallstrom/urlscheme_vim_in_iterm) to be the protocol handler that will pass along the command string to zsh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a wrong order: `nocorrect exec …`, not `exec nocorrect …`:

> nocorrect
>
> Spelling correction is not done on any of the words.  This must appear before any other precommand modifier, as it is interpreted immediately,  before  any  parsing  is  done.

In the paragraph just above this it is stated that `exec` is also a precommand modifier. Thus you are violating “must appear before any other precommand modifier” requirement.